# thread performance in Julia

Tags: julia

My attempt at parallel Julia code does not improve performance with increased number of threads.

The code below runs in about the same time whether I set JULIA_NUM_THREADS to 2 or 32.

```
using Random
using Base.Threads

rmax = 10
dr = 1
Ngal = 100000000

function bin(id, Njobs, x, y, z, w)
    bin_array = zeros(10)
    for i in (id-1)*Njobs + 1:id*Njobs
        r = sqrt(x[i]^2 + y[i]^2 + z[i]^2)
        i_bin = floor(Int, r/dr) + 1
        if i_bin < 10
            bin_array[i_bin] += w[i]
        end
    end
    bin_array
end

Nthreads = nthreads()

x = rand(Ngal)*5
y = rand(Ngal)*5
z = rand(Ngal)*5
w = ones(Ngal)

V = let
    VV = [zeros(10) for _ in 1:Nthreads]
    jobs_per_thread = fill(div(Ngal, Nthreads),Nthreads)
    for i in 1:Ngal-sum(jobs_per_thread)
        jobs_per_thread[i] += 1
    end
    @threads for i = 1:Nthreads
        tid = threadid()
        VV[tid] = bin(tid, jobs_per_thread[tid], x, y, z, w)
    end
    reduce(+, VV)
end
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time spent in the threaded loop is negligible compared to the rest of the operations.  You're also allocating arrays with size depending on the number of threads, so when using multiple threads you spend even (slightly) more time in the memory allocation.

---

Please, have a look at https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/ if you care about performance.  In particular, avoid at any cost global variables (they kill performance) and put everything in functions, that are also easier to test and debug.  For example I rewrote your code as:

```
using Random
using Base.Threads

function bin(id, Njobs, x, y, z, w)
    dr = 1

    bin_array = zeros(10)
    for i in (id-1)*Njobs + 1:id*Njobs
        r = sqrt(x[i]^2 + y[i]^2 + z[i]^2)
        i_bin = floor(Int, r/dr) + 1
        if i_bin < 10
            bin_array[i_bin] += w[i]
        end
    end
    bin_array
end

function test()
    Ngal = 100000000
    x = rand(Ngal)*5
    y = rand(Ngal)*5
    z = rand(Ngal)*5
    w = ones(Ngal)

    Nthreads = nthreads()
    VV = [zeros(10) for _ in 1:Nthreads]
    jobs_per_thread = fill(div(Ngal, Nthreads),Nthreads)
    for i in 1:Ngal-sum(jobs_per_thread)
        jobs_per_thread[i] += 1
    end
    @threads for i = 1:Nthreads
        tid = threadid()
        VV[tid] = bin(tid, jobs_per_thread[tid], x, y, z, w)
    end
    reduce(+, VV)
end

test()
```

Performance with one thread:

```
julia> @time test();
  3.054144 seconds (33 allocations: 5.215 GiB, 11.03% gc time)
```

Performance with 4 threads:

```
julia> @time test();
  2.602698 seconds (65 allocations: 5.215 GiB, 9.92% gc time)
```

If I comment the `for` loop in `test()` I get the following timings.  One thread:

```
julia> @time test();
  2.444296 seconds (21 allocations: 5.215 GiB, 10.54% gc time)
```

4 threads:

```
julia> @time test();
  2.481054 seconds (27 allocations: 5.215 GiB, 12.08% gc time)
```